# Data structure for storing large datasets

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, data-structures, large-data

I have millions of random positive and negative 32-bit integers that need to be stored in some data structure. The function must exit if the data structure already contains that particular value. Can you please suggest some highly memory efficient data structure that'll achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Dataset, data*set*, maybe some kind of [set data structure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) could be used? At least to begin with.

Comment: When you say "millions", how many are they? 16GB, which is common memory size in modern computers, will hold EVERY ONE of the 4096 million numbers are possible in 32 bits. Using a bitmap, you can reduce that by a factor of 32, so 0.5GB.

Comment: _Random_ positive and negative 32-bit integers? _If_ storing them is a problem, don't, get a new one once needed. (Storing _all_ of them naively takes 16GB - problem?) Function? A function that does not need to exit if `the data structure` does _not_ `contain that particular value`? Try and supply enough information to find a solution: what operations are to be supported and in which order (allowing insertions and deletions between queries, insertions only, or none; value changes). Which operations occur often enough to be concerned about efficiency, does anything known about the data help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to accept some false positives, I'd suggest you to use a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Using as little as 10 bits per element and 7 hash functions, you'd have less than 1% false positives probability and no false negatives at all.

Answer (score 0):

In term of memory efficiency it's hard to beat `std::vector` since all data are packed together. And since you have to be fast is search, better to store them sorted, so that you can binary-search them.

Unless you can either:

- compress the numbers themselves using linear prediction and encoding them in differential way (or whatever higher order polynomial): this makes packing more efficient, but makes direct access (ad binary search) impossible
- If the numbers are each other independent and are results of a time-invariant computation, don't store them, but recompute as they are needed.

In any case less memory you take the harder will be having the number back to be searched (That's a physical principle, not related to programming, but to the information theory)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said whether you need to maintain the elements in unsorted order - I'm assuming not....

> The function must exit if the data structure already contains that particular value.

You've got about 4 billion possible 32-bit values, and you're talking about some seemingly "few" million numbers.  To me, that suggests something like this:

```
vector<uint16_t> bucket[65536];
```

For Q million elements, you'll average 15*Q elements per bucket... enough for the overheads of `std::vector<>` to be a small percentage of memory use, and yet few enough to be very quick to re-sort a bucket after an addition or - alternatively - do linear searches.

If you think K will be larger, make more buckets covering smaller ranges of values.  If you're not too sure, you may want some dynamic sizing, or to find a different approach altogether.  If K approaches 128 you may want to use a `bitset` for the entire thing.

Given a logical value of `v`, you can use a combination of masking off the high bits (e.g. `(uint32_t)v >> 16`) to indentify the bucket, with binary search or insertion for e.g. `v & 65535` inside the bucket....